# В значении(,) близком к прямому(,)

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> Сочетание «в свою очередь», если оно употреблено в значении(,) близком к прямому(,) или в значении ‘в ответ; со своей стороны’, вводным не является.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Сочетание «в свою очередь», если оно употреблено в значении близком к прямому или в значении ‘в ответ; со своей стороны’, вводным не является.***

Запятые не нужны по [«Розенталю», пункт 2-2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108):

> Не обособляются определения, стоящие после существительного, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении: Марья Дмитриевна приняла вид достойный и несколько обиженный (Т.) — сочетание слов приняла вид не имеет смысла; Чернышевский создал произведение в высшей степени оригинальное и чрезвычайно замечательное (Д. П.); Вы выбрали судью довольно строгого (Л.); Вернер — человек замечательный по многим причинам (Л); Если вы человек себя уважающий… то непременно напроситесь на ругательства (Дост.); Попытки писать просто приводили к результатам печальным и смешным (М. Г.) — без последующих двух определений существительное не выражает нужного понятия; Это была улыбка необыкновенно добрая, широкая и мягкая (Ч.); Нас встретил мужчина стройный и приятной наружности; С портрета смотрит на вас лицо умное и весьма выразительное (ср.: …лицо женщины, поразительно красивое); Все они оказались учениками хорошо подготовленными; Деление — действие обратное умножению; Мы часто не замечаем вещей куда более существенных; Вошёл пожилой человек с черепом лысым, как у апостола.

Как раз здесь именно такой случай:

*Сочетание «в свою очередь», если оно употреблено **в значении** или в значении ‘в ответ; со своей стороны’, вводным не является.*

Существительное с предлогом *в значении* **не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО.**

Это предложение из справочника Розенталя, и там стоят запятые. А стоят они по первому пункту.

Comment: Ну почему же?! Там же нельзя изъять его! Ошибка, значит.