# О правильной записи предложения из правила Розенталя

Tags: пунктуация, определения

**[Цитата из Розенталя, пункт 9 (7):](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)**

*Сочетание **«в свою очередь»**, если оно употреблено **в значЕнии, близком к прямОму,** или **в значении «в ответ; со своей сторонЫ»**, вводным не является и запятыми не выделяется.*

1. **Знаки поставлены верно**. Это СПП, придаточное условное в середине предложения.

Оборот "близком к прямому" **обособляется** в постпозиции (после определяемого существительного) по основному правилу. Смысловым центром он **не является**, что видно по расстановке логических ударений.

2. Но вот мнение **[из другого ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476049/%D0%92-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83)**, в котором предлагается не обособлять оборот:

   ```
   Существительное с предлогом в значении не выражает нужного 
   смысла и нуждается в определении.
   ```
3. Да, нуждается, но **обособленное** определение тоже подойдет. А вот вопрос об обособлении **самого определения** зависит от структуры предложения и оборота.
4. Оборот **«близком к прямОму»** как я думаю, **ВСЕГДА** обособляется, так как ударение падает не на прилагательное, а на зависимое слово.

А как думаете вы: правило Розенталя записано верно? И почему **здЕсь обособлен оборот**? И всегда ли он **вообщЕ** обособляется?

Comment: Правило записано верно, и думать нечего :)). А в том ответе есть дополнение о правильности обособления (автор разобрался, но не стал полностью менять).

Comment: Думать нечего? Разобрался?  Розенталь-то прав, но почему был задан вопрос? Значит, были сомнения. Тогда нужно ИЗМЕНИТЬ ответ. И я не уверена, что все разобрались. Сначала был смысловой центр, а потом перестал им быть? А почему? Или пусть напишет опровержение. И комментарий остался: "Ну почему же?! Там же нельзя изъять его! Ошибка, значит.". А  еще к оформлению вопросы: зачем все выделять жирным шрифтом? Выделять надо те места, на которые следует обратить внимание. Как-то надо ИСПРАВИТЬ всю тему. Или пусть так и остается?

Comment: Согласен, что ответ выглядит совсем неправильно. Сначала всё о том, что обособлять не надо, а потом приписка с противоположным выводом.

Comment: А как участнику намекнуть об этом? Ответ принят, будет  ли он слушать?  А вот сама тема обособления не так проста, мне их сомнения и поиски понятны.

Comment: Я думаю, что если существительное нуждается в определении и не выражает без него смысла достаточного, запятые нужны. Если акцент на ПРИЗНАКЕ существительного, то нужны. Но я больше склоняюсь к варианту, где запятые не нужны) Без оборота уже совсем другое получится.

Comment: Любопытно! Так что с записью правила: Розенталь ошибся или нет?  И будете ли вы исправлять ту тему? Можно, к примеру, дать второй ответ с вашим окончательным мнением. Я вот считаю, что оборот вообще нельзя обособить.

Comment: @Максим Что-то вы меня запутали: "...если существительное нуждается в определении и не выражает без него смысла достаточного, запятые нужны." Вроде ж всё наоборот, и там вы приводите как раз правило об этом. // А ещё помню ваши слова: "Поймите, главное — неразрушенная структура. Помните, я в вопросе одном (Он, может быть, дома, но, может быть, нет) объяснял? Смысл — второй план, структура — первый".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Это с вводными словами так!

Comment: @Максим Какая разница с чем? Любой обособленный оборот (причастый, деепричастный, придаточное предложение) можно убрать без нарушения стуктуры.

Comment: Ищ предлржения можно убрать всë, кроме грамматической основы. В предложении: _в значении близком к прямому_ — нельзя «оторвать», они как бы едины. Смысл нарушается, а вот структура нет. Мы изымаем исключительно ради проверки, не более. Я уже устал объяснять!

Comment: Серьëзно, я просто уже не знаю, как объяснить, чтоб до вас дошло про структуру и смысл. ЭТО РАЗНЫЕ ВЕЩИ!

Comment: @Максим  Тогда не пишите такие категоричные вещи: "Смысл — второй план, структура — первый",   "Главное — СТРУКТУРА. Я не говорю вам, что эти предложения по смыслу будут эквивалентны и тождественны, но если структура не нарушается, то предложение в принципе верное".

Comment: Нельзя оторвать? "В значении близком к прямому".  Это неразложимое словосочетание? Смелое утверждение))  Мне за "емкую культуру"  до сих пор минусы ставят (не далее как сегодня).

Comment: Вводные слова не являются членами предложения, но без них может искажаться смысл. А чтобы проверить, ставится ли запятая, например, между союзом и вводным словом, проверяют по структуре, а не смыслу. А вот обороты являются членами предложения, поэтому они могут синтаксически связываться по смыслу с другими словами и не выделяттся запятыми. Обороты проверяют как по структуре, так и по смыслу: смысл — (не)вхождение в состав сказуемого; структура — (не)корректный в целом вид предложения (именно вид, а не смысл).

Comment: @Sharon Без потери смысла нельзя, а так можно.

Comment: Максим, у нас есть сочетание: "близкое к прямому значение". Оно разложимое? По структуре и смыслу? ЗНАЧЕНИЕ; ср. 1. Основное смысловое содержание чего-л. З. понятия. В общем, добрались до несвободных словосочетаний.

Comment: Интересная точка зрения: оторвать нельзя, а обособить можно)  Оторвать и рядом положить? Классная философия – соответствует действительности.